# Sunspot rails search, deny creating facets by condition

Tags: sunspot, faceted-search, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr, facet

I use sunspot_rails gem in full text searching in Ruby on Rails,

I added boolean field ('show_facet') to my model Product,
and to solr index

Then I want to do next:

- if 'show_facet' == true then show Product in search list and facets list

  if 'show_facet' == false then show Product only in search list

I read all docs, forums and api but I can't find answer to this question

Could I do this with sunspot?

```
Model Code
searchable do
    string  :keywords, multiple: true    
    string  :status
    boolean :show
    boolean :show_facet
    time    :updated_at
    text    :keyword_long, stored: true
    text    :jtitle, stored: true
    integer :id
    integer :company_id
  end


Controller

  def show
    @product_search = OpenStruct.new(params[:product_search])
    @search = search_plain
  end

  private

  def search_plain
    basic_search do |search|
      search.fulltext(@product_search.fulltext) do
        fields *(%w[jtitle keyword_long])
        highlight :keyword_long
        highlight :jtitle
      end
    end
  end

  def basic_search
    Product.solr_search do |search|
      yield search
      search.with(:show, true)
      search.order_by(:random)
      search.paginate page: params[:page], per_page: 10
      search.with(:keywords).all_of(@product_search.keywords)
      search.facet :keywords
    end
  end
```

I need include in facet(:keywords) only facets from product with show_facet = true, but show all products in search (with show_facet true or false)

Comment: provide ur code, u r using for search in controller and code of model.

Comment: I provided code, maybe anything else?

Comment: U mean u want to include "search.facet :keywords" this line for search only when show_facet=true, right?

Comment: no 'search.facet :keywords' should always exists
but inside this facet should be only facets from Products where show_facet=true

Comment: you mean option for facet should  only come from those product for which show_facet =true?.. right?